# Do integers need to be escaped

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there any point in escaping an integer in a query after it's converted with `intval()`?

I'm using the integer like so:

```
$sql .= " LIMIT " . $this->db->escape(intval($offset))  . ", 10";
```

Comment: There's no need to escape integers, as long as you've validated that the value actually is an integer - but you should always do that validation if $offset comes from client-side input

Comment: You shouldn't be building query strings like that anyway; use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, [intval](http://php.net/intval) will always return an integer (`0` on failure).

Comment: Correctly, (int) and intval() always return sql-safe values.

Answer (score 2):

No. because as a result of intval you can't receive nothing except the number.